# SSRS Report Duplicates Flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report

I'm presently making a report on ssrs from a Great Plains Dynamics DB.

It's a pretty simple report with a few columns. Everything works fine but in GP, when creating an Invoice or a Return bill, sometimes GP is gonna give the same Bill ID. It doesn't really shows as a duplicated because for GP, an Invoice and a Return can/could have the same ID because they are not the same type. Don't ask me why..

So for my report, when I start a research from a multiples values parameters with my SopNumber (Bill ID) it gives me the right information. But now I would like to have a flag on those information that equals the bill ID and has Invoice and Return at the same time.

Since it is normal for GP to have 2 different type of document for the same ID, I cannot ask my report to remove the return or the invoice cause in different case, an Invoice could be the important document and in an other case, the return.

In my tablix, I do not show the Bill ID, because I don't need the information except when there is this "duplication".

I would also like after the flag (line highlited), that on the top of my report, a sentence shows something like : "Those documents are in conflict : 000123123". So with this information showing my ID, I can now go in my multiple values parameter and remove this number.

I wanna achieve those 2 flags because I'm making a calcul from my documents amount and if those 2 would be there, it would make my calcul wrong.

I hope you guys can help me. If so, thank you very much in advance!

I worked on a couple of different expressions but never got the result I wanted. Use previous statement and equals but couldn't find how to make it look like is equals to Invoice and Return and SopNumber equals the same.

```
select CASE SOP10200.SOPTYPE
                WHEN 1 THEN 'QUOTE'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'ORDER'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'INVOICE'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'RETURN'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'BACK ORDER'
                WHEN 6 THEN 'FULLFILLMENT ORDER'
                END AS SOPTYPE,
                sop10200.SLPRSNID,
                sop10200.XTNDPRCE as ExtendedPrice,
                sop10200.SOPNUMBE,
                iv00101.ITMCLSCD as FAMILYCLASS,
                sop10100.DOCDATE

from sop10200
left join iv00101 on sop10200.ITEMNMBR = iv00101.ITEMNMBR
left join sop10100 on sop10200.SOPNUMBE = sop10100.SOPNUMBE

WHERE SOP10100.DOCDATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2035-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
union all

select  CASE SOP30300.SOPTYPE
                WHEN 1 THEN 'QUOTE'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'ORDER'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'INVOICE'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'RETURN'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'BACK ORDER'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'FULLFILLMENT ORDER'
                END AS SOPTYPE,
                sop30300.SLPRSNID,
                sop30300.XTNDPRCE as ExtendedPrice,
                sop30300.SOPNUMBE,
                iv00101.ITMCLSCD as FAMILYCLASS,
                sop30200.DOCDATE

from sop30300
left join iv00101 on sop30300.ITEMNMBR = iv00101.ITEMNMBR
left join sop30200 on sop30300.SOPNUMBE = sop30200.SOPNUMBE

WHERE SOP30200.DOCDATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2035-01-01 00:00:00.000'

ORDER BY SOPNUMBE desc
```

Comment: left join sop10100 returns regular inner join result. Move the sop10100 condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: can you show us your dataset result? It could be as simple as deriving a row number based on your bill ID and if it has a count of more than 1 then it is a duplicate.. use TSQL to get most if not all of what you desired and use SSRS to present it!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want a way to see if there is a duplicate record for the report and use that in a calculation?

You could do a subquery to retrieve a count, and if that is more than 1 than you have a duplicate record

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT *, (IF 
    (SELECT Count(S1.SOPTYPE) FROM sop10200 S1 WHERE T1.BillID = S1.BillID ) > 1 THEN "Duplicate " ELSE "" END) AS DuplicateCheck
FROM sop10200 T1
```

The above solution will give you a value you can use on each page to report whether or not that it has a duplicate BillID.

Comment: Actually no, in my report, there will probably have duplicates once a week. So when there's one, I want to bring a flag that tells me that these 2 documents have the same ID. When the flag's gonna be lifted with a color or with the sentence that shows the ID, I will then be able to remove this document from my parameter that has a multiples values field. In doing so, I will have a calculation that doesn't have those 2 documents in it. Then after that, by hand I will do my calculation for this one document. FYI, this in not in sql server but a report in SSRS

Comment: You are throwing a lot of terms around that muddy the desired solution. You can use parts of that SQL query to help you identify in the SSRS report what there are duplicate records. Not sure what' I want to remove this document from my parameter' is. Are you wanting a solution that notifies you before the report is ran that there are duplicates? Or a report expression/field that tells you there is a duplicate record?

Comment: When I use my report, I fill 3 fields (parameters) a "date from" , "date to" and a BillID. The BillID parameter can have multiples values in it. So let's say I have a client, and I want to get 8 of his invoices in my report, I enter those 8 invoices number in my BillID field (parameter). When I'm ready, I run the report and then the report is gonna tell me if one of these 8 BillID as a duplicates by highlighting them with a color and/or having an empty field that's gonna say "These documents are duplicates: 'Bill_ID'  "   Hope it looks more clear

Comment: Please see my edit. This solution should work unless I'm missing something